# C# object to byte[]

Tags: c#, arrays

Is there a known why to convert a specific object, lets say `Student` to a `byte[]`.

Not including `Serialization`/`Deserialization`.

A way I thought of doing it was to extract it from memory when it is created at first, but I believe this is a little far reaching and I think there is an easier way to do it.

I was thinking to try and do a `TypeConverter`, but as I understand it will try and match it to `byte[]` and not actually retrieve its `byte[]` equivalent.

Any input would help, I have seen the google created serializer too, but there has to be an in built way to get the `byte[]` equivalent of an object.

Any confirmation or constructive criticism is welcome.

Comment: What is your scenario for "not including serialization deserialization"? Binary serialisation sounds like the exact use case for this

Comment: Why "not including serialization"? It sounds like just that.

Comment: Most types of any complexity will have reference types, which can point elsewhere in memory.  Grabbing the in-memory image doesn't make sense.  Binary Serialization/Deserialization is your best bet.

Comment: I want to figure out how to grab it or convert it a different manner. I was wondering if anyone else has another way other then serialization.

Comment: Okay, lets put it another way - what are you going to *do* with this array of bytes? What purpose do they serve? Are you sure that this magical array of bytes obtained not via serialization is going to serve that purpose?

Comment: How can it be "Magical Array of Bytes" you do realize objects when created are stored as bytes/bits... if there is no other way to get the byte[] of an object in C# then Jesus there was not much forward thinking :S

Comment: Directly retrieving the actual underlying byte[] that corresponds to the object's field store in memory can be done using unverifiable CIL, but the result is pretty worthless, as reference types will be included as numerical pointers with no way to reconstruct the object correctly.

Comment: Great thanks, another one actually answering my question, cheers. I will read into that just to learn more which was the point of the question... Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: There was a lot of forward thinking put into the question of "how do I take this object and create a binary blob that's actually useful?" and that system is called serialization. But since you've ruled out that mechanism, you shouldn't be surprised that some other mechanism hasn't been provided. As many have pointed out, the actual contents of memory at any particular point in time aren't terribly useful for any purpose that most of us can imagine.

Comment: There was actually a lot of forward thinking, if you actually used the parts of the question that state that I have read into other possible areas, also the part where I state I wanted confirmation. On top of this yes the memory might be useless, but I didn't ask if it was or not I was asking for the sake of learning something more which is the whole "Question" thing.

Comment: I was responding to your "Jesus there was not much forward thinking" comment and observing that there was a lot of forward thinking but that you're apparently dismissive of such thinking. There was a lot of thinking about the fact that obtaining access to raw memory was pointless and that, for any practical purposes, what we want is a set of bytes that are actually useful. You apparently want a set of bytes to put on display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this:

```
TypeConverter obj = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(objectMessage.GetType());
byte[] bt = (byte[])obj.ConvertTo(objectMessage, typeof(byte[]));
```

Comment: There we go finally, this is what I have written in my code, I have not tested it yet I was just looking for confirmation as already stated... Cheers mate.

Comment: @VasaSerafin: Wait... so you already wrote this code but couldn't be bothered to try running it? You just thought you would ask us instead, even though you didn't include the code you wanted confirmation on???

Comment: No I was confused as I already said.. I was confirming that it would not try to cast it. I also stated that I was going to use TypeConverter... That is why there was a please confirm my thoughts.

Comment: @VasaSerafin: And what happens if you try to cast something that cannot be cast? You get an error. So you could have confirmed it yourself by running the code which you clearly state in the comment above `"this is what I have written in my code"`

Comment: I could have, I admit that, but I was researching into other aspects of it as welling, e.g. reading into the TypeConverter which is why I didn't mention anything in my original question about writing the actual code to use the object, I was only suspecting it may/not help.

Comment: So where does the "converter" that turns students into arrays of bytes come from? And how come this is not "serialization"?

Comment: @VasaSerafin: Stack Overflow is not the place to have discussion about how things work, or what options are available to implement a requirement. It is about answering **specific** question. Please have a read though the FAQ about what kind of questions you should ask

Answer (score -1):

Below is the code to convert object in to byte.

```
var msg = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode(ObjectName));
```

Comment: Doesn't give you the object bytes but a byte array of the JSON representation of the object, completely different

Answer (score -2):

Use the [BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx).

```
byte[] ToByteArray(Object obj)
{
    if(obj != null)       
    {
        using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
           var bf = new BinaryFormatter()
           bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
           return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: This was Taumantis' answer, but he deleted it.

Comment: Could be, I didn't see that. Or are you saying is the exact code or what?

Comment: Why not make the method `static`? — I think Taumantis deleted his answer because the Original Poster complained this was "serialization". But personally I cannot see how turning a `Student` into an array of bytes would not be "serialization".

Comment: static, private, public, extension method, etc. is an unimportant detail, don't you think?

Comment: I don't see how this is does not involve serialization.